# Read random chunks from text file

Tags: python, out-of-memory, deep-learning

For a deep learning model I need to load my data by batches. For every epoch (full iteration over all the data) every row needs to be passed once, but it's important that the data is fed in a random order to the algorithm. My dataset is too big to read it fully in memory. It's sequence data with a variable length, the input format can be changed since it's a dump from a cluster that my other script outputs. Currently it's some meta info per row and then the sequences split by ';'.

My current solution is a generator that shuffles all the line numbers, chunks them up in 4 pieces and reads the file, parsing the lines that match the chunk line numbers. It yields batch sized sequences until there is nothing left, and then it parses the next chunk of line numbers. It works, but I feel like there might be a better solution. Who has a better workflow? This is a problem I run into regularly. The problem is that I'm fully scanning the file for every chunk, every epoch. Even though I can get it to work with just 4 chunks, with 30 epochs that is 120 times reading a big file.

Comment: *"it's important that the data is fed in a random order to the algorithm"* Sequential disk I/O APIs weren't designed for this kind of crazy. - Signed, someone who knows nothing about "deep learning"

Comment: I would make a set of the file with `set(file_obj)`.  Then use `random.sample` to get the right number of random elements.

Comment: @zondo doesn't that load the whole file contents into memory?

Comment: How random are you looking for? Cause you could copy over the data, randomize the file and then read it in, or if you have  multiple files randomly choose a file, and then randomly choose a starting place and length and then keep track of what you've already read with a bitmap

Comment: Yes that was another option I looked at, maybe splitting the data into a number of memory appropriate files, then read those files in a random order and train over the randomized sequences of those files might be good enough. I'll read up on the theory

Comment: I assume you are storing one row per line in a text file. It could be worthwhile using fixed sized rows so that you can quickly seek to a given row without having to scan the whole file.

Comment: That is a nice solution, though the variance in sequence length is huge. I also thought I could maybe read it once and keep track of the position of the new lines. How do I quickly jump to a position in a text file in Python?

Comment: Yeah, fixed record size is not so practical when the variance in sequence length is huge. But you can use the file's [`.seek`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.seek) method to jump to a given offset in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build an index of the lines in memory (which requires a single pass through the file, but not all in memory) and then you can access lines randomly and fast.

This isn't robust (no validation/range-checking, etc.) but:

```
import sys

BUFFER_LEN = 1024


def findNewLines(s):
   retval = []
   lastPos = 0
   while True:
      pos = s.find("\n", lastPos)
      if pos >= 0:
         pos += 1
         retval.append(pos)
         lastPos = pos
      else:
         break
   return retval


class RandomAccessFile(object):
   def __init__(self, fileName):
      self.fileName = fileName
      self.startPositions = [0]
      with open(fileName, "rb") as f:
         looking = True
         fileOffset = 0
         while (looking):
            bytes = f.read(BUFFER_LEN)
            if len(bytes) < BUFFER_LEN:
               looking = False
            newLines = findNewLines(bytes)
            for newLine in newLines:
               self.startPositions.append(fileOffset+newLine)
            fileOffset += len(bytes)

   def GetLine(self, index):
      start, stop = self.startPositions[index],self.startPositions[index+1]-1
      with open(self.fileName, "rb") as f:
         f.seek(start)
         return f.read((stop-start)-1)



raf = RandomAccessFile('/usr/share/dict/words')


print raf.GetLine(0)
print raf.GetLine(10)
print raf.GetLine(456)
print raf.GetLine(71015)
```

output is:

```
python indexedFile.py
A
Aaronic 
abrim 
flippantness
```